# Flutter drag and drop items between multiple lists

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I'm trying to implement a two-level drag and drop list in Flutter with draggable sections and draggable items within those sections, that can be dragged from one section to another. I found the [drag_and_drop_lists](https://pub.dev/packages/drag_and_drop_lists) package. Functionality-wise it is exactly what I'm looking for, but it seems to be no longer maintained and didn't feel smooth when I tried it out.

I also looked at [Draggable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) and [DragTarget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DragTarget-class.html). Combined with columns it seems to be easy to implement the required functionality, but again, it doesn't feel smooth. Some issues

- The drag target has to have a minimum height to be able to precisely drop something on it, which means I need to add additional space to the beginning or end of the list
- Wrapping list items in the drag target works, but it feels unnatural. The drag targets should instead be offset by 50% item height (this is how dragging works with [ReorderableListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html)), but that doesn't seem to be possible.
- It doesn't animate (although that's probably something I could figure out somehow...)

Do you have any recommendations, other than to reimplemented the `ReorderableListView` (which seems quite complicated)?